# Autohotkey time between clicks

Tags: timer, autohotkey

Iv been recently interested in developing a way to measure the times between my mouse clicks for research however im unsure what functions autohotkey has available to help with this. I firstly tried to get a measure of the exact time using :

```
FormatTime, ssnow, %A_Now%, ss
```

The problem with this was that subtracting one time from another is apparently impossible in autohotkey according to some forums i have searched and the result when testing also produced an empty value.

Is there a way to initiate a counter when the left button is down and then stop the timer when the button is released?

Here is the code I have been working on:

```
clickTime := 0
lastClick := 0
~LButton::
FormatTime, ssnow, %A_THEN%, ss
lastClick=%A_THEN%
~LButton Up::
FormatTime, ssnow, %A_Now%, ss
clickTime=%A_Now%
MsgBox (%clickTime% - %lastClick%  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
~LButton::
    StartTime := A_TickCount
    While(GetKeyState("LButton", "P"))
        continue
    ToolTip % A_TickCount - StartTime
return
```

or:

```
~LButton::
    StartTime := A_TickCount
    keywait, LButton, L
    ToolTip % A_TickCount - StartTime
return
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, and actually reduced the amount of code id expected to have to use in autohotkey.